# Instantiate Angular JS service using - injector.get()

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular 1.x application. Now that there is a use case where in I have to access the Angular 1.x Services / Factories in ES6 Classes which are not part of or registered with Angular JS. In short I would want to do something like export an Angular Service and import in ES6 class. I know this is not directly possible but will there be a work around ?

So I have a service like

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').service('ServiceOne', function () {
        return {
            property: value
        };
    });
})();
```

and now there is an ES6 class another (service file)...

```
import angular from 'angular';

// const $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']);
// const ServiceOne = $injector.get('ServiceOne');
// const ServiceTwo = $injector.get('ServiceTwo');

class Es6Service {
    constructor() {
        //this.serviceOne = ServiceOne;
        //this.serviceTwo = ServiceTwo;
    }

    methodOne() {
        // code 
    }

    methodTwo() {
        // code
    }
}

export default Es6Service;
```

I know that `injector.get('serviceName')` can get us the service instance, in my case I am getting an error of unknown provider. My assumption is that the angular module reference is missing perhaps here.

If that is the case then how can I get the Module reference here ? or there is some other way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks strange but should work:

```
import angular from 'angular';

let _$injector;
angular.module('myApp').run($injector => _$injector = $injector);

class Es6Service {
    methodOne() {
        // Cannot call this method until angular initialize
        return _$injector.get(...)
    }
```